# Using Which Not Where

Tags: relative-clauses

I have read the related questions answered here but still don't know how I can convince a learner not to use **where** in the *second gap*. They simply believe whenever a word refers to a place (no matter whether it is an entity or not), they have to use this relative adverb.

*I have to say that my favourite place in the world is the village **where** I was born. I've travelled all over the world but it's still the place **which** I love most.*

Comment: The difference is that in integrated relative clauses "where" typically functions as an adjunct of place in the relative clause, whereas "which" typically functions as subject, object or complement of a preposition.

Comment: Can you rephrase that for a learner and make an answer out of it?

Comment: @James: But the whole point is teaching relative clauses and they need to know how relative pronouns/adverbs work properly.

Comment: Even so, it is an answer, not a comment.  And it should be written as such.  I think @Bill can write a good answer, in such a way that both the M.N and other learners can understand.  Personally I'd not use any conjunction  "... the place I love most".  For general language learning ideas there is also [languagelearning.se]

Comment: @James: The lines I've written here are part of an exercise in which learners have to complete the gaps using only "which or where".

Comment: @BillJ: So based on what you've said, "which" works as an "object"; a role that "where" cannot play, right?

Comment: It refers to the village as a 'thing' which you love, not as a place where something is happening.

Comment: @M.N Objects are invariably noun phrases, not preposition phrases. In "This is the hotel where we stayed last year", "where" functions in the relative clause as an adjunct of place", not an object.

Comment: @M.N Objects are invariably noun phrases, not preposition phrases. In "This is the hotel where we stayed last year", "where" functions in the relative clause as an adjunct of place", not an object. We understand "We stayed **at this hotel** last year".

Comment: "Where" is a **relative adverb**, and i[t has the syntactic status of a **prepositional phrase**](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/which-where-2). That's why we don't add ***to*** with ***where*** - but we do need a preposition *(**at, in, to,...**)* with ***which***.

Comment: No: "where" is **not** a relative adverb. It belongs to the category (part of speech) **preposition** and its function in the relative clause is '**adjunct** of place'

Comment: "where I was born" is a relative clause, introduced by the word wh-word where. And "the place which I love (the) most" can be reduced to: the place I love most.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers: Since you did not agree with BillJ in comments above, could you write an answer to my question and tell me what your take is?

Comment: The place *that* I love most.

Answer (score 0):

> *I have to say that my favourite place in the world is the village*
> ***where** I was born. I've travelled all over the world but it's still the*
> *place **which** I love most*.

The difference is that in integrated (defining) relative clauses, "where" functions as an adjunct of place in the relative clause, whereas "which" typically functions as subject, object or complement of a preposition.

Note that in modern grammar, "where" is analysed as a preposition, not an adverb, where it can be paraphrased as "in/at/on/from" some place".

"*I was born **in some village***" [adjunct of place.]

"*I love **the place** most*" [object]

Comment: "I love the place most" is not grammatical in English.

Comment: @Lambie Wrong. It's meant to be the core of the relative clause which is "which **I love __** most" where gap = "the place"

Comment: @Lambie Read my last comment! Obviously relative clauses can't stand alone. We show the relative clause to demonstrate the function of the relatavised element in the relative clause, which here is object of "love".  See?

Comment: You can post: "I love the place most" but it is meaningless, even to illustrate something. That is not the way to illustrate something.

Comment: @Lambie It's the normal way of demonstrating **syntactically** the function of the R element in the relative clause. Again the relative clause is "which I love __ most", where R  is represented by gap. Take that on board, as I don't intend to repeat it.

Comment: No one demonstrates syntax with a meaningless gap. Where you fill in the gap must make sense.

Comment: @BillJ I have mentioned your answer in my answer. If I have been unfair or incorrect, please let me know so I can either delete or correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to BillJ’s answer with a more old-fashioned vocabulary. I would classify “where” here as a relative pronoun (not a relative adverb and not as a preposition) just as “which” is a relative pronoun.

But I agree with BillJ that when used in modern English as a relative pronoun it usually incorporates a preposition of place or is the object of a preposition.

> the village where I was born

means

> the village **in** which I was born

For another example

> the village where I am going

means

> the village **to** which I am going

On the other hand,

> the place which I love

does not require any preposition, implicit or explicit and so precludes the use of “where.”

This is my answer, and, if I have mischaracterized BillJ’s answer, I apologize.